# How to create sub array from array

Tags: javascript

I have large data structure to manipulate and I have some problems sorting similar data into sub array.

```
var arr = [2016-12-16, 2016-12-16, 2016-12-17, 2016-12-17, 2016-12-17, 2016-12-17, 2016-12-18, 2016-12-18, 2016-12-19];
```

I wanna sort like this.

```
[[2016-12-16, 2016-12-16], [ 2016-12-17, 2016-12-17, 2016-12-17, 2016-12-17],[2016-12-18, 2016-12-18] [2016-12-19]]
```

Comment: Are those elements (dates?) supposed to be strings? Right now you're subtracting numbers.

Comment: So you want to sort them by day? Also, to agree with @qxz, I am reasonably certain that you need to make sure those are strings because otherwise you're doing the math of something like 2016-12-16 which is 1988

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array into an array of arrays by using a object as a hash:

```js
var arr = ['2016-12-16', '2016-12-16', '2016-12-17', '2016-12-17', '2016-12-17', '2016-12-17', '2016-12-18', '2016-12-18', '2016-12-19'];

var result = arr.reduce(function(r, item) {    
  (r.hash[item] || (r.hash[item] = r.arr[r.arr.push([]) - 1])).push(item);
  
  return r;
}, { arr: [], hash: {} }).arr;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a dictionary (which JS objects naturally act as).

```
var datesArray = [ "2016-12-16", "2016-12-16", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-18", "2016-12-18", "2016-12-19" ]; //I've corrected the syntax for this to make each date a string, rather than a sequence of subtractions

var datesCount = {};
datesArray.forEach(function(date){
    if(!datesCount[date])
        datesCount[date] = []
    datesCount[date].push(date);
});
```

At this point, you have a set of group arrays, each containing every instance of a particular date. You can iterate over it with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and put each array into the larger array OR you could just use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

try to divide the code to sub problems-

1. first, convert all element to strings (before writing a function).
2. copy the array to manipulate without changing original.
3. sort elements.
4. identify repeated elements.
5. create sub arrays for repeated elements.

this a code I've written for a differend purpose and modified it for the explanation.
there might be more effient ways to write it, i'm still learning..

```
const dateStringSort = (array) => {
//assign to a new array - wont change exist array
    const arr = [].concat(array);
//sort elements
    arr.sort();
//identify repeated elements and group them to sub arrays.
    const arr1 = []; //assign another array to prevent inifinty loops
    while (arr.length>0){
        let i = arr[0];
        let filtered = arr.filter(item=>item===i);//return new array with all reapeted elements
        arr1.push(filtered); //push the filtered array to new array as a sub array
        arr.splice(0,(filtered.length)); //delete all the repeated elements from arr to prevent double sub araays
    };
//return new array
return arr1;
};

//run function
const originArray = ["2016-12-16", "2016-12-16", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-17", "2016-12-18", "2016-12-18", "2016-12-19"]; 
const newArray = dateStringSort(originArray);
```